# DBvisualizer character as question mark

Tags: mysql, character, dbvisualizer

I am using DBvisualizer and Im struggling with one thing. I have this simple statement:
`update table_name set column_name = replace(column_name,'š','s');`
The thing is, that in DBvisualizer when i run this, it is processed as: `update analysis set Soubor = replace(Soubor,'?','s')`
The 'š' character is replaced in statement by question mark, which means that it does not work as it should. Anybody know how to setup dbvisualizer to work properly with such characters? I tried to change properties, but nothing helped.
Thanks

Comment: Most likely a character set problem whereas the server can't properly encode 'š'. Which database are you using?

Comment: it should be MariaDB 5.55.34. Weird thing is, that when I use Adminer web application, it works with these special signs correctly, so I think problem is in DBvis.

Comment: Just tried with a vanilla installation of MariaDB 10.1.19-MariaDB and MariaDB connector/J 2.0.3. It works as expected. If you need further assistance use Help->Contact Support in DbVisualizer to post a support ticket.

Comment: thanks roger, I was using mysql connector and that was probably the issue. Tried mariadb connector and it works fine.